# Transfer data measurement between client (raspberry pi) server (http/amqp/mqtt)

Tags: java, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, networking, bandwidth

I want to measure bandwidth for message transfer between client and server using different protocols: in both case, like client(raspberry pi) to server and server to client(raspberry pi).

Let's say I am sending/receiving the following json message from Ruby or Java program to either AMQP (RabbitMQ broker), Mqtt (Mosquito broker) or HTTP server (rails application).

**Message**:

```
{   
"unit1": { "state": [ { "ON": "200", "time": "12212" } ] }
}
```

How can I calculate the amount of bandwidth required (kilobytes or bytes) to send/receive this message? Event if I use Ruby or Java REST program to send this message to HTTP server, how can I calculate these required data?

Is there any API in Ruby or Java to calculate from application layer, or in TCP layer, can I use any tools to calculate a particular port and IP address? Can anyone tell me what other approaches are there to do this measurement?

Comment: You want to use the Rabbitmq management system: http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: @Anthony Is it possible to measure bandwidth for a single message transmission using this  RabbitMq management system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some approach with different tools like tcpdump, but I got [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), provide a lot of convenient features and it has nice graphical front-end, plus some integrated sorting and filtering options. Solved this query sending individual JSON data from client to server and find easy way to measure bandwidth information for individual communication.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt there's better ways, but an easy one I've used is to send the request to a local instance of **nginx** (or whatever http server you prefer) and then just check the logs for the request_body size value.